# how to make flashcards that the user gets wrong appear more often - visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a flashcard application which displays flashcards that the user has created

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    btnDisplay.Enabled = False
    Dim index = rand.Next(dt.Rows.Count) ' generates index in the range 0 .. Count - 1
    txtFront.Text = dt.Rows(index)(2).ToString()
    txtBack.Visible = False
    txtBack.Text = dt.Rows(index)(3).ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub btnEasy_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEasy.Click
    Dim index = rand.Next(dt.Rows.Count) ' generates index in the range 0 .. Count - 1
    If txtBack.Visible = True Then
        txtFront.Text = dt.Rows(index)(2).ToString()
        txtBack.Visible = False
        txtBack.Text = dt.Rows(index)(3).ToString()
    Else
        MsgBox("Please first reveal the back of the flashcard")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnGood_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGood.Click
    Dim index = rand.Next(dt.Rows.Count) ' generates index in the range 0 .. Count - 1
    If txtBack.Visible = True Then
        txtFront.Text = dt.Rows(index)(2).ToString()
        txtBack.Visible = False
        txtBack.Text = dt.Rows(index)(3).ToString()
    Else
        MsgBox("Please first reveal the back of the flashcard")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnHard_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHard.Click
    Dim index = rand.Next(dt.Rows.Count) ' generates index in the range 0 .. Count - 1
    If txtBack.Visible = True Then
        txtFront.Text = dt.Rows(index)(2).ToString()
        txtBack.Visible = False
        txtBack.Text = dt.Rows(index)(3).ToString()
    Else
        MsgBox("Please first reveal the back of the flashcard")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnReveal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReveal.Click
    txtBack.Visible = True
End Sub
```

The current code displays a random flashcard that is stored in an access database. I was wondering if there is a way where flashcards that the user gets wrong appear more often(kind of like anki).
So, if the user clicks the btnEasy button, the flashcard is less likely to come up again and if the user presses the btnHard button, the flashcard is more likely to come up.

Comment: Put your flashcards in a list and select a random item from the list by index. If you want an item to be more likely to be selected than other items add it to the list multiple times. If you have a `List(Of Integer)` that contains the numbers 1 to 10 once each and you lick a random item, each number is equally likely to be selected. If you add the number 3 a second time, so you now have 11 items, the number 3 is twice as likely to be randomly selected than all the other values. You might add all numbers twice and then add 3 a third time, so 3 is then 50% more likely than the other numbers.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate(this is for a school project), how would I put flashcards that are stored in an external database into a list?

Comment: Maybe put some thought into it for yourself first, then come back if you encounter an actual issue. To get you started, you can do whatever you like with data you retrieve from a database. It's just data, e.g. `Strings`, `Integers`, etc. If you want to make a list of objects containing that data, that's what you should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each card, you can track some `GoodUntil` [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0) variable which represents the time at which it should be shown again, like [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) does. When cards are first created, you set that value to [Now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime.now?view=net-5.0) so the card can be immediately shown to the student. Then, every time the student sees the card, you update `GoodUntil` to a new date based on what the student clicks (Easy, Good,  Difficult, etc). For example, if the user clicks:

- Easy: set `GoodUntil` to 10 days from now
- Good: set `GoodUntil` to 2 days from now
- Difficult: set `GoodUntil` to 5 minutes from now.

When looking for the next card to show, look at each card's `GoodUntil` value and [compare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compare?view=net-5.0) it with Now. If it's less than 0, it's ready to be shown again.

This is a basic way to do this but should work well. You should also track a score for each card which will track how well a student is doing with the card. If the student clicks Easy on a card, you want to keep track of that and next time, if he clicks Easy again, you can set the `GoodUntil` date to 30 days, then 60 days if he clicks Easy again, etc.

When no more cards can be found, you can display some message to the student telling them they are done studying.